# Is there a way to sign a document?

Tags: formatting

I was wondering if we could sign a document in such a way that the signature information is shown on the printed copy of the document itself (and ideally, in the electronic files as well).

I have been including my name in the file, but sometimes this may not be an option.

To do so, I guess we could manually create an input cell and configure the alignment, and what not, but that only covers the first or last page.

Is there a functionality like in word where you can include things like signature in the peripheral parts of any pages of the document?

Comment: Like `PageHeaders`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not entirely cleat what OP wants and they didn't respond to the question in comments section.